# SQLAlchemy: about self referential relation (error: no attribute '_sa_instance_state')

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I want to implement some `many to many` and `self referential` mapping kind like the graph of keywords in a `keyword net`. For example, "apple" is a child of "juicy fruits", at the same time, "apple" is the parent of many "specific species of apples", and "juicy fruits", of courses have many parents like "things eatable". In short a `many to many` relationship. And, they are both instances of keyword class(`self referential`). I defined it as following,

```
kw2kw_table=Table('kw2kw_table',Base.metadata,
              Column('child_id',Integer,ForeignKey('kw_table.id'),primary_key=True),
              Column('parent_id',Integer,ForeignKey('kw_table.id'),primary_key=True),
             )

class KW(Base):
    __tablename__='kw_table'
    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    name=Column(Unicode(28),unique=True)
    parents=relationship('KW',
                 secondary=kw2kw_table,
                 primaryjoin=id==kw2kw_table.c.child_id,
                 secondaryjoin=id==kw2kw_table.c.parent_id,
                 backref='children',
                 )
    def __init__(self,name,parent=None):
        self.name=name
        self.children=[]
        if parent==None: #default to a root keyword
            self.parents.append(self)
        else:
            self.parents.append(parent)
```

in my view file:

```
...   
    keywordName = request.params['keyword']
    parentName = request.params.get('parent',u'')
    if parentName:
        parent=DBSession.query(KW).filter(KW.name==parentName)
        if parent: #if parent exists
            new_kw=KW(keywordName,parent)
        else:
            parent=KW(parentName)
            new_kw=KW(keywordName,parent)
    else: #if the parent was not provided
        new_kw=KW(keywordName)
    DBSession.add(new_kw)
...
```

but, when the view is submitted with`(keyword,parent)` , I got an error:

```
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 910, in fire_append_event
value = fn(state, value, initiator or self)
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1138, in emit_backref_from_collection_append_event
child_state, child_dict = instance_state(child), \
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

I gooogled it, but couldn't figure it out. Please help.

### ----------update------------------------

details: 
https://gist.github.com/actor2019/5417471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to invoke the Query so that you get an instance back, right now you're passing the Query object to your Session:

```
parent=DBSession.query(KW).filter(KW.name==parentName).first()
```

Comment: Thank you. The error disappeared, and I added `DBSession.add(parent)` between lines `parent=KW(parentName)` and `new_kw=KW(keywordName,parent)`. But it still didn't work( new keywords are not committed after I submitted the data) ... It seems that the `__init__` didn't do what I expected.

Comment: are you flushing/committing the session?

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Pyramid doc says that "Pyramid takes care of committing: it commits at the end of a request or aborts if there’s an exception." Anyway, even I do the flushing manually, it didn't work. I have pasted the console output here:  https://gist.github.com/actor2019/5417471

Comment: Do you have 'pyramid_tm' in your pyramid.includes in our ini file?  That's the module that does the magic to auto commit at the end of a web request.